# resize an image using canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hi want to resize an image using canvas but can't get it to work...
I want the image to be 100px * 100px, is there any way to solve this?
I have tried googleing and trying but can't get it to work...

I also tried changing the img size in css but this doesn't help either, please help me!

```
function getBase64Image(img) {
// Create an empty canvas element
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = img.width;
canvas.height = img.height;


// Copy the image contents to the canvas
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

// Get the data-URL formatted image
// Firefox supports PNG and JPEG. You could check img.src to guess the
// original format, but be aware the using "image/jpg" will re-encode the image.
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
```

}

I also realized that I need to rotate it how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get a ratio of the width and apply it to the height.

```
var ratio = 100 / img.width; // 100 for desired width in px
canvas.width = img.width * ratio;
canvas.height = img.height * ratio;

ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

typed on phone so forgive small mistakes.

Comment: thanks! I now realize that i need to rotate it 90 degrees, do you have any pointers for that?

Comment: I answered your question so ideally you should mark my answer as correct and give it an up vote if desired.  If you would like to ask another question in the forums feel free, but I know from experience your new question has been answered many times on SO, so a quick search would likely give you the answer.